# Change Post Status From Front End

Tags: posts, front-end

I am using the code in a page below to let users delete their posts from the front in. I have wp-admin totally blocked off to site users.

What i want to do is when they click the delete button the post actually goes into draft or pending mode so there is still a record of the post but the front end cant view it.

```
<!-- buyer-home.php -->
<?php
 if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) {
 set_query_var( 'postid1', $_POST['postid'] );
 wp_delete_post( get_query_var( 'postid1'), true ); }; ?>
 <?php query_posts( array( 'author' => $current_user->ID,'post_status' =>  'publish' , 'post_type' => array(    'user_lists' )  ) ); ?>
   <?php if ( !have_posts() ): ?>
  <div class="info" id="message">
 <p>
   <?php _e( 'No Lists found.', 'lists' ); ?>
   </p>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
 <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<header class="entry-header">
<h1 class="entry-title center">Your Lists</h1>
</header>
 <div class="entry-content">
<div class="table style1">
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td style2">
      <h2>Date And Time</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="td">
      <h2>Delete</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
     <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
     <?php echo '<div class="tr"><div class="td style2">';
    echo '<a href="'; the_permalink(); echo '">'; the_time('F j, Y'); ?> at
      <?php the_time('g:i a'); echo '</a>';
         echo '</div><div class="td">'; ?>
    <?php  change_post_status( the_ID, 'private'); ?>
     <form class="delete-list" action="" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="postid" value="<?php the_ID(); ?>" />
      <input class="more-button" type="submit"  value="Delete" />
    </form>
    <?php  echo '</div></div>'; ?>
     <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
    <div class="tr">
        <div class="td style2">
      <h2>Date And Time</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="td">
        <h2>Delete</h2>
    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div><!-- .entry-content --> 
    </article><!-- #post --> 
     <!-- /buyer-home.php -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply replace

```
wp_delete_post( get_query_var( 'postid1'), true );
```

with

```
wp_update_post( array( 'ID' => get_query_var( 'postid1' ), 'post_status' => 'draft' ) );
```

That is assuming that the rest of your logic does already work.

Comment: My code works just fine, im not sure what logic has to do with it. however yours gives errors

Comment: When using "logic" the way I meant it, it's interchangeable with "code". Also, it was not my intention to say that your code isn't okay, I simply have not read through all of it. I was saying that the above will work, provided that the rest of your code does. And that still holds - if you are getting errors, it is **not** from the above one-liner.

Comment: no it wasnt, i was copying over the closing }; when pasting your code. not your fault sorry. about to get to testing it.